# template.builtins.append(register) not working on django 1.8 but it was working on django1.6

Tags: django-1.8

have query on following code which is working on django 1.6

from django import template register = template.Library()

@register.filter def lt(a,b): return float(a) < float(b); @register.filter def gt(a,b): return float(a) > float(b);

template.builtins.append(register)

but same code is not working on django 1.8 and throwing below error

```
        template.builtins.append(register) Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'builtins'
```

why it is throwing error?  if any one has already got this issue ,provide your input?